# How to count tableA rows when joined to tableB

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an Access database, TableA has a foreign key to TableB.  TableB contains a column with four possible values.  I need to count the number of rows in TableA for one of the four values in TableB.  This was my initial attempt:

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) As TableACount 
FROM        TableA 
INNER JOIN  TableB ON TableA.fk_tableB = TableB.pk_tableB 
WHERE       TableB.[value] = 1
```

Here's another attempt:

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) As TableACount,
            TableB.[value]
FROM        TableA 
INNER JOIN  TableB ON TableA.fk_tableB = TableB.pk_tableB 
WHERE       TableB.[value] = 1
GROUP BY    TableB.[value]
```

The result returned in both queries appears to be the number of TableA rows times the number of TableB rows they are joined to.  How can I get just the number of TableA rows?

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) As TableACount,
            TableA.fk_tableB
FROM        TableA 
INNER JOIN  TableB ON TableA.fk_tableB = TableB.pk_tableB 
WHERE       TableB.[value] = 1
GROUP BY    TableA.fk_tableB
```

Comment: @PeterKipe, pls check

Comment: still getting a value much too large.

Comment: Sorry Grace - these are large tables and I had some bad data.  Looks like your answer works.  Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKipe, you're welcome. Would you pls mark it as answer? Thks

Answer (score 1):

You may either use a distinct count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.pk_tableA) AS TableACount 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.fk_tableB = b.pk_tableB 
WHERE b.[value] = 1;
```

Or, use exists logic:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TableACount
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.pk_tableA = a.fk_tableB AND b.[value] = 1);
```

Comment: Tim, your exists solution works perfectly too.  Thanks!